# typescript stateless (functional) component warning using destructing?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I got error when trying to do

```
import * as React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

const Person: React.FC = ({ name }) => <div>{name}</div>;

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Person name="james" />
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
render(<App />, rootElement);
```

What's the problem at line 4?

https://codesandbox.io/s/cocky-silence-wxs2s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue isn't destructuring, but rather you have to provide a type definition for your component's props. One way to do so is to create a `Props` type and pass it as a generic to `React.FC`:

```
type Props = {
  name: string;
};

const Person: React.FC<Props> = ({ name }) => <div>{name}</div>;
```

Comment: you're right. but how about warning in this line? ```<Person name="james" />```

Comment: @Jennifer it's the same problem. `<Person name="james" />` will show a typescript compile error because the prop `name` doesn't exist on the type definition for `Person` (until you implement the typing I recommended)